Unable to execute Action in another controller using AJAX call
I am trying to execute code in my MVC application that in my web application, a user when logging in, will have to verify their phone number first before they can click on any menus in my application.  I am using the ErrorController functionality in MVC so that it prevents user from almost doing anything in the application.  I am trying to execute an action that sends them a 2FA text message with a code and then displays a modal popup and returns a PartialView where they can enter the code so that they can thereafter proceed with the application.
In my errorcontroller, I first tried RedirectToAction method to get to the VerifyPhoneNumber action but read somewhere that you cannot use it on PartialViews.   So I am trying to use as shown below, an AJAX call to the action.  However, it does not seem to execute the VerifyPhoneNumber action and I even set a breakpoint.  What I am doing wrong or do I need to do this logic another way?   Thanks.
Action code that calls the main page:
public ActionResult UnverifiedPhoneNumber()
{
    return View();
}

The main page where I am trying to make an AJAX call to VerifyPhoneNumber action to display popup to that user can enter their 2FA code:
@model HandleErrorInfo
@{
    const string Title = "Verify Phone Number";
    ViewBag.Title = Title;
}
<script>
    alert('hello');
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Account/VerifyPhoneNumber",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
                success: function(data) {
                  // Handle the response data here
                  console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(error) {
                  // Handle errors here
                  console.error(error);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
<h1 class="text-danger">@Title</h1>
<h2 class="text-danger">Before you can continue to use the site, verify your phone number</h2>

Action code in another controller that I am trying to execute sends a 2FA SMS Code and does a popup:
   [Display(Name = "Verify Phone Number", Description = "Verify Phone Number")]
    public async Task<PartialViewResult> VerifyPhoneNumber()
    {
         ....Send SMS code to user's phone number .....
        Context.Log("Opened Verify Phone Number modal");
        return PartialView("_VerifyPhoneNumber", new VerifyPhoneNumberModel());
    }


Could you try make the async false in your ajax and try
<script>
    alert('hello');
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Account/VerifyPhoneNumber",
                async: false,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",


Can you please edit your answer and explain why you believe this will fix the problem?

Thanks Yat, but it is still not working.  One thing I notice in my Developer Tools that for some reason it says its getting to my VerifyPhoneNumber page, but it is not hitting the breakpoint I have for that controller of that page.

If someone can even suggest a different approach to get the VerifyPhoneNumber approach, I am open to that also.

I feel like the async is giving problem. Therefore you may try to remove the async and give it a try.

Thanks for the suggestion but I didn't have the async in the first place and get same issue.   I originally in my controller I did this: return RedirectToAction("VerifyPhoneNumber", "Account");   but for some reason it also does not execute the VerifyPhoneNumber action.  If you have any ideas there, let me know.
